# ASP.NET MVC 5 routing optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've an Action in my ApiController that I want to invoke from a specific link, so I created this simple route

```
[Route("Rest/GetName/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetName(string name) {
    // cut - code here is trivial but long, I just fill in an object to return as Json code
    return Json(myObject);
}
```

It works fine but I want to make the parameter optional. According to [documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) adding a question point at the end of the parameter name in the route should be enough

```
[Route("Rest/GetName/{name?}")]
```

This way I get an error if I don't provide the optional parameter, so

```
.../Rest/GetName/AnyName --> ok
.../Rest/GetName/ --> error (see below)
```

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost/miApp/Rest/GetName'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Rest' that matches the request."}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Web API requires to explicitly set optional values even for nullable types and classes.

Use default value to optional parameter:

```
[Route("Rest/GetName/{name?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetName(string name = null) {
    // cut - code here is trivial but long, I just fill in an object to return as Json code
    return Json(myObject);
}
```

And don't forget about routing registration:

```
httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions:

1. **Try Optional Parameter**

   ```
      [Route("Rest/GetName/{name?}")]
      public IHttpActionResult GetName(string name = null) {
          // cut - code here        is trivial but long, I just fill in an               
          obj ect to return as 
          `enter code here`Json code
          return Json(myObject);
            }
   ```

2.**Set PreFix on controller first**

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Rest")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RestController : ApiController
    {
         [Route("/GetName/{name}")]
         public IHttpActionResult GetName(string name = null) 
         {
         // cut - code here is trivial but long, I just fill in an object
         to  return as Json code
         return Json(myObject);
         }
     }
```

3.**Write parameter before action name in route**

```
   [RoutePrefix("api/Rest")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RestController : ApiController
    {
         [Route("{name}/GetName")]
         public IHttpActionResult GetName(string name = null) 
         {
         // cut - code here is trivial but long, I just fill in an object
         to  return as Json code
         return Json(myObject);
         }
     }
```

Hopefully this will help you to resolve your problem.Thanks